# Узнать букву из таблицы

Tags: javascript, шифрование

Есть таблица описывающая отношение буквенно-цифровой переменной(центральный столбец) и составного ключа(Ключ в дальнейшем примере формируется из  отношением первого и третьего столбца одного ряда)
Помогите составить код нахождения буквы по ключу
Пример:
[image: пример]

Comment: Чтобы вставить картинку, используйте кнопку с картинкой при редактировании вопроса.

Comment: Всё бы хорошо но на телефоне с андроид где мне её увидеть

Comment: Из вопроса ничего не ясно. У вас таблица в excel?

Comment: @sentsentimo Тогда загрузить на imgur, или просто на какой-нибудь гугл-драйв, вставить ссылку, а кто-нибудь мимопроходящий вставит уже как изображение.

Comment: Да, но можно хоть в блокноте её сделать. Как можно показать пример в картинке?

Comment: http://imgur.com/f3ahXYT вот

Comment: Ваш вопрос про Java или Javascript?